# nx publishable library is failing on target app with `The target entry-point "@org/thingA" has missing dependencies:`

Tags: angular

I have a [nx](https://nx.dev/) mono repo that have multiple interdependent libraries that are publishable. Within the monorepo everything works fine. However when I import a library in a different repo I get failures that it's missing dependencies.

```json
{
  "name": "@org/thingA",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.7",
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@org/thingB": "file:dist/libs/thingB/index.d.ts",
    "@org/thingC": "file:dist/libs/thingC/index.d.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

No errors on build. But then on the other repo I get:

```
Error: The target entry-point "@org/thingA" has missing dependencies:
 - @org/thingB
 - @org/thingC
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?